# Rebuild sql query to sum date from two tables

Tags: sql, firebird

I need a solution extension that I received and it is visible at the link [How to get correct year, month and day in firebird function datediff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551257/how-to-get-correct-year-month-and-day-in-firebird-function-datediff). I have problem with connect data from two tables. I have got data with dates in two table KP and KPS. I know that I have to add data from second table in SQL query in that place where is definition of KP2 but I don`t know how to do this. Should I use join?

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    KP3.id_contact,
    (KP3.D2-KP3.D1) / (12*31) AS Y,
    ((KP3.D2-KP3.D1) - ((KP3.D2-KP3.D1) / (12*31)) * 12 * 31) / 31 AS M,
    CAST(MOD((KP3.D2-KP3.D1) - (((KP3.D2-KP3.D1) / (12*31)) * 12 * 31), 31) AS INTEGER) AS D
FROM
    (SELECT
         KP2.id_contact, SUM(KP2.D1) AS D1, SUM(KP2.D2) AS D2
     FROM
         (SELECT
              KP.id_contact, 
              DATEDIFF(MONTH, KP.DATE_FROM, KP.DATE_TO) / 12 AS Y, 
              CAST(MOD(DATEDIFF(MONTH, KP.DATE_FROM, KP.DATE_TO), 12) AS INTEGER) AS M,
              EXTRACT(YEAR FROM KP.DATE_FROM)*12*31+EXTRACT(MONTH FROM KP.DATE_FROM)*31+EXTRACT(DAY FROM KP.DATE_FROM) D1,
              EXTRACT(YEAR FROM KP.DATE_TO)*12*31+EXTRACT(MONTH FROM KP.DATE_TO)*31+EXTRACT(DAY FROM KP.DATE_TO) D2 
          FROM
              KP) AS KP2
    GROUP BY 
        KP2.id_contact) AS KP3
```

I show this on example. I have data in table KP like this

```
ID    DATE_FROM    DATE_TO
------------------------------
1     2018-02-08   2019-12-01
```

and in table KPS I have data like this:

```
ID    DATE_FROM    DATE_TO
------------------------------
1     2017-02-20   2018-01-01
```

Result of query should be like this:

```
2Y 8M 7D
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: In what way do you need to connect data from table KP and KPS? What is the logic here? Why will this combination result in 2Y 8M 7D?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess what you could have mean.

Maybe you meant to pick the most earlier (`MIN`) date between all the source tables, then the most late and count days in between?

Or maybe you wanted to count days per-job in all source tables, and the nsum those days per-worker?

Dunno, here is BOTH solutions, built from simplistic blocks fuirther and further into end results. It also uses the data from the questions you link, for self-checking.

Here is the script you can tweak and see how it goes:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=6d99adde7194631bff47be49e5f92dc9

The results are either **2 years 9 months 2 days** or **2 years 8 months 1 day** depending upon the guesswork about what you meant by joining the source tables.

Cherry-pick the sub-queries that you need and cull away those you do not need.

> ```
> select rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') as version from rdb$database;
> ```
>
> ```
> | VERSION |
> | :------ |
> | 3.0.5   |
> ```

> ```
> -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030543/rebuild-sql-query-to-sum-date-from-two-tables
>
> create table KPS1 (
>   ID integer not null,
>   DATE_FROM date not null,
>   DATE_TO date not null
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table KPS2 (
>   ID integer not null,
>   DATE_FROM date not null,
>   DATE_TO date not null
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create index KPS1_workers on KPS1(id)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create index KPS2_workers on KPS2(id)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into KPS1 values (1, '2018-02-08', '2019-12-01')
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into KPS2 values (1, '2017-02-20', '2018-01-01')
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> -- this data sample taked from
> -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551257/how-to-get-correct-year-month-and-day-in-firebird-function-datediff
> insert into KPS1 values (2, '1988-09-15', '2000-03-16')
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into KPS1 values (2, '2000-03-16', '2005-02-28')
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from KPS1 union all select * from KPS2
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | DATE_FROM  | DATE_TO   
> -: | :--------- | :---------
>  1 | 2018-02-08 | 2019-12-01
>  2 | 1988-09-15 | 2000-03-16
>  2 | 2000-03-16 | 2005-02-28
>  1 | 2017-02-20 | 2018-01-01
> ```

> ```
> -- sadly, the topic starter did not say what he wants to do with his many sources of data
> -- so multiple interpretations are possible!
>
> -- here we are counting days from the first date to the last date, one row per worker
>
> -- finding the minimum and maximum dates from ALL the sources
> --  (multitude of rows in multitude of tables)
> -- very simple to write and read, it however would be bad on long tables
> -- because ID indexes hidden by UNION and not available for further, outer queries
> --   FULL-SCAN in natural order and post-merge external sorting would occur
>
> Select ID as id_contact, Min(DATE_FROM) as DATE_FROM, Max(DATE_TO) as DATE_TO
> From (select * from KPS1 union all select * from KPS2)
> Group by ID
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_CONTACT | DATE_FROM  | DATE_TO   
> ---------: | :--------- | :---------
>          1 | 2017-02-20 | 2019-12-01
>          2 | 1988-09-15 | 2005-02-28
> ```

> ```
> -- finding the minimum and maximum dates from ALL the sources
> -- this one is harder to write and read
> -- but should be better for execution: it allows use of indexes by ID be propagated
>
> -- This optimized query works fine with the data presented by topic starter
> -- where each source tables has exactly one row for one and the same worker.
>
> -- It will not work so fine when some workers are missed from some tables.
> -- Fixing it will make the query even more complex to write and read
>
> Select KPS1.ID as id_contact, 
>   IIF(KPS1.DATE_FROM < KPS2.DATE_FROM, KPS1.DATE_FROM, KPS2.DATE_FROM) as DATE_FROM,
>   IIF(KPS2.DATE_TO < KPS2.DATE_TO, KPS2.DATE_TO, KPS1.DATE_TO) as DATE_TO
> From KPS1, KPS2
> Where KPS1.ID = KPS2.ID
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_CONTACT | DATE_FROM  | DATE_TO   
> ---------: | :--------- | :---------
>          1 | 2017-02-20 | 2019-12-01
> ```

> ```
> Select ID_CONTACT, DateDiff(day, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT From
> (
>   Select ID as id_contact, Min(DATE_FROM) as DATE_FROM, Max(DATE_TO) as DATE_TO
>   From (select * from KPS1 union all select * from KPS2)
>   Group by ID
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_CONTACT | DAYS_COUNT
> ---------: | :---------
>          1 | 1014      
>          2 | 6010
> ```

> ```
> -- alternatively, here counting days per-job, many rows may happen for the same worker
>
> select a.*, datediff(day, a.DATE_FROM, a.DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT from KPS1 a
>   union all
> select b.*, datediff(day, b.DATE_FROM, b.DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT from KPS2 b
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | DATE_FROM  | DATE_TO    | DAYS_COUNT
> -: | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
>  1 | 2018-02-08 | 2019-12-01 | 661       
>  2 | 1988-09-15 | 2000-03-16 | 4200      
>  2 | 2000-03-16 | 2005-02-28 | 1810      
>  1 | 2017-02-20 | 2018-01-01 | 315
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ID as ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT FROM
> (
>   select a.*, datediff(day, a.DATE_FROM, a.DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT from KPS1 a 
> ) 
> GROUP BY ID_CONTACT
>
>     union all
>
> SELECT ID as ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT FROM
> (
>   select b.*, datediff(day, b.DATE_FROM, b.DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT from KPS2 b
> )  
> GROUP BY ID_CONTACT
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_CONTACT | DAYS_COUNT
> ---------: | :---------
>          1 | 661       
>          2 | 6010      
>          1 | 315
> ```

> ```
> WITH PER_SOURCE_SUMMER AS 
> (
>   SELECT ID as ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT FROM
>   (
>     select a.*, datediff(day, a.DATE_FROM, a.DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT from KPS1 a 
>   ) 
>   GROUP BY ID_CONTACT
>
>     union all
>
>   SELECT ID as ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT FROM
>   (
>     select b.*, datediff(day, b.DATE_FROM, b.DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT from KPS2 b
>   )  
>   GROUP BY ID_CONTACT
> )
>
> SELECT ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT 
> FROM PER_SOURCE_SUMMER
> GROUP BY 1
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_CONTACT | DAYS_COUNT
> ---------: | :---------
>          1 | 976       
>          2 | 6010
> ```

> ```
> -- Now, having TWO interpretations of the task and TWO implementations of days counter
> -- we finally can come up with conversion from precise but hard to feel DAYS 
> -- to imprecise but easy to digest Y-M-D
>
> WITH SOURCE_MIN_MAX AS
> (
>   Select ID_CONTACT, DateDiff(day, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT From
>   (
>     Select ID as id_contact, Min(DATE_FROM) as DATE_FROM, Max(DATE_TO) as DATE_TO
>     From (select * from KPS1 union all select * from KPS2)
>     Group by ID
>   )
> ),
>
> PER_SOURCE_SUMMER AS 
> (
>   SELECT ID as ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT FROM
>   (
>     select a.*, datediff(day, a.DATE_FROM, a.DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT from KPS1 a 
>   ) 
>   GROUP BY ID_CONTACT
>
>     union all
>
>   SELECT ID as ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT FROM
>   (
>     select b.*, datediff(day, b.DATE_FROM, b.DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT from KPS2 b
>   )  
>   GROUP BY ID_CONTACT
> ),
>
> SOURCE_PER_JOB AS
> (
>   SELECT ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT 
>   FROM PER_SOURCE_SUMMER
>   GROUP BY 1
> ),
>
> KP_DAYS AS
> (
>   SELECT 1 as METHOD, A.* FROM SOURCE_MIN_MAX A
>      union all
>   SELECT 2 as METHOD, B.* FROM SOURCE_PER_JOB B
> )
>
> SELECT * from KP_DAYS
> ```
>
> ```
> METHOD | ID_CONTACT | DAYS_COUNT
> -----: | ---------: | :---------
>      1 |          1 | 1014      
>      1 |          2 | 6010      
>      2 |          1 | 976       
>      2 |          2 | 6010
> ```

> ```
> WITH SOURCE_MIN_MAX AS
> (
>   Select ID_CONTACT, DateDiff(day, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT From
>   (
>     Select ID as id_contact, Min(DATE_FROM) as DATE_FROM, Max(DATE_TO) as DATE_TO
>     From (select * from KPS1 union all select * from KPS2)
>     Group by ID
>   )
> ),
>
> PER_SOURCE_SUMMER AS 
> (
>   SELECT ID as ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT FROM
>   (
>     select a.*, datediff(day, a.DATE_FROM, a.DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT from KPS1 a 
>   ) 
>   GROUP BY ID_CONTACT
>
>     union all
>
>   SELECT ID as ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT FROM
>   (
>     select b.*, datediff(day, b.DATE_FROM, b.DATE_TO) as DAYS_COUNT from KPS2 b
>   )  
>   GROUP BY ID_CONTACT
> ),
>
> SOURCE_PER_JOB AS
> (
>   SELECT ID_CONTACT, SUM(Days_Count) as DAYS_COUNT 
>   FROM PER_SOURCE_SUMMER
>   GROUP BY 1
> ),
>
> KP_DAYS AS
> (
>   SELECT 1 as METHOD, A.* FROM SOURCE_MIN_MAX A
>      union all
>   SELECT 2 as METHOD, B.* FROM SOURCE_PER_JOB B
> )
>
> SELECT
>     KP_DAYS.method, KP_DAYS.id_contact, KP_DAYS.days_count,
>     FLOOR(KP_DAYS.DAYS_COUNT / 365.25) AS Y
>   , FLOOR( (KP_DAYS.DAYS_COUNT - (FLOOR(KP_DAYS.DAYS_COUNT / 365.25) * 365.25) ) / 30.5) AS M 
>   , CAST(MOD((KP_DAYS.DAYS_COUNT) - (((KP_DAYS.DAYS_COUNT) / 365.25) * 365.25), 30.5) AS INTEGER) AS D
> FROM KP_DAYS
> ```
>
> ```
> METHOD | ID_CONTACT | DAYS_COUNT | Y  | M  |  D
> -----: | ---------: | :--------- | :- | :- | -:
>      1 |          1 | 1014       | 2  | 9  |  2
>      1 |          2 | 6010       | 16 | 5  |  2
>      2 |          1 | 976        | 2  | 8  |  1
>      2 |          2 | 6010       | 16 | 5  |  2
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like this :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTableA, #TestTableB
CREATE TABLE #TestTableA (DFA DATE, DTA DATE)
CREATE TABLE #TestTableB (DFB DATE, DTB DATE)

INSERT INTO #TestTableA
SELECT '2018-02-08','2019-12-01'

INSERT INTO #TestTableB
SELECT '2017-02-20','2018-01-01'

SELECT  CAST(SUM(DaysQTY) / 365 AS VARCHAR(4)) + 'Y ' +
        CAST((SUM(DaysQTY) % 365) / 30 AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'M ' +
        CAST((SUM(DaysQTY) % 365) % 30 AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'D' AS Result
FROM    (   SELECT  DATEDIFF(DAY,DFA,DTA) AS DaysQTY
            FROM    #TestTableA
            UNION   ALL
            SELECT  DATEDIFF(DAY,DFB,DTB) AS DaysQTY
            FROM    #TestTableB
        )   t
```

Comment: this totally would not do in Firebird. That `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` and `SELECT '2017-02-20','2018-01-01'` is just broken non-standard SQL. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0  Also, why on Earth use insert-from-select instead of standard `insert into t(x,y,z) VALUES (xxx,yyy,zzz)` i wonder...

Comment: @Arioch'The: what's worse: `+` is not used to concatenate strings in SQL - the operator for that is `||`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i did not even look into operators, or perhaps i would also notice C-style `%` for taking remainder :-D